# Printing data in a specifc cell in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

The following code works fine. However I need to paste the data starting from a specific row in a column. Here as per the code I can paste the data in column 'C' but if I want to start the pasting from 'C5' for instance how do I change the coding? Thanks for the help.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()


    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim rData As Range, rCell As Range, rFrom As Range, rTo As Range
    Dim lRightCol As Long
    Dim ass As Integer

    ass = 4

    With ActiveSheet
        lRightCol = .Range("C3").Column
        Set rData = .Range(.Range("A3"), .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        For Each rCell In rData
            Set sh = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set sh = Worksheets(rCell.Value)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Not sh Is Nothing Then
                Set rFrom = rCell.Resize(1, lRightCol)
                With sh
                    Set rTo = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(1, lRightCol)
                End With
                rFrom.Copy rTo
            End If
        Next rCell
    End With


End Sub
```

I tried to change the code to following but didn't work.

```
 Set rTo = .Range("C5" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(1, lRightCol)
```

Comment: `Set rTo = .Range("C5")`

Comment: @simoco then only the first data point in the series will be copied. because you're removing End(xlUp)......

Comment: really? have you tried it?

Comment: yup! just tried replacing `Set rTo = .Range("C5" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(1, lRightCol)` with yours but didnt work mate. any other suggestion? :)

Comment: `Set rTo = .Range("C" & Application.Max(5,.Cells(.Rows.Count,"C").End(xlUp).Row + 1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments. you can use:

```
Set rTo = .Range("C" & Application.Max(5,.Cells(.Rows.Count,"C").End(xlUp).Row + 1))
```